# Acts-as-taggable-on - Is there a method to delete a tag with ownership?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

For my rails app I need to be able to remove a current users owned tag with a controller action.

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) you can view tags with `@item.tag_list` but this won't show tags with owners.  For that you should use `@item.all_tags_list`.

To add tags you can do `@item.tag_list.add("tag1")` and to add a tag with an owner you can do `@some_user.tag(@item, :with => "tag1", :on => :tags)`.

To remove a tag you can do `@item.tag_list.remove("tag1")`, but I can't find a way to remove a tag with an owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using these methods:

```
def stringify(tag_list)
    tag_list.inject('') { |memo, tag| memo += (tag + ',') }[0..-1]
end

def remove_owned_tag 
    @some_item = Item.find(params[:id])
    owned_tag_list = @some_item.all_tag_list - @some_item.tag_list
    owned_tag_list -= [(params[:tag])]
    @tag_owner.tag(@some_item, :with => stringify(owned_tag_list), :on => :tags)
    @some_item.save   
end
```

I found this buried in another answer but I can't find it now to credit the author.

EDIT: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797298/4584963